# QML read and set property within SplitHandle from SplitView

Tags: qt, qml, splitview

In the following example, how can I read and set the property dummy in rect1 and rect2? I am not sure how to read a property from a loaded component in this case.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

SplitView {
    id: splitView
    anchors.fill: parent

    handle: Rectangle {
        id: handleRect
        property bool dummy: false
        implicitWidth: 4
        implicitHeight: 4
        color: SplitHandle.pressed ? "#81e889"
            : (SplitHandle.hovered ? Qt.lighter("#c2f4c6", 1.1) : "#c2f4c6")

        Rectangle: {
          visible: dummy
          ...
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        implicitWidth: 150
        color: "#444"
        Component.onCompleted: {
            handleRect.dummy = true // Does not work
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect2
        implicitWidth: 50
        color: "#666"
    }
}
```

Using handleRect.dummy within either rect1 or 2 does not work due to TypeError: Cannot read property 'dummy' of undefined.

Comment: Set an `id` for the Rectangle, then read the `dummy` property, or try using `handle.dummy`.

Comment: @smr That doesn't work. I've updated my post with that information.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you can use this approach. It's not the best, but it does the work. first, define a `property bool dummy` in `SplitView`, then assign it to the `handle` (`property bool dummy: splitView.dummy`), and change `splitview.dummy`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but that doesn't work either because the property in the SplitView would not be unique for each rectangle, meaning if one rectangle change that property, it would also affect the other rectangle as well, when it should be different instead.

Comment: How about using `splitView.children`? It appears that the created separators can be accessed using `splitView`'s `children`, starting at index 1 (if I'm not mistaken). For instance, the first separator would be `children[1]`.

Comment: @smr Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed. How did you get to this conclusion? I've read the source code of SplitView and tried to access the children in different ways without any luck. Can't believe it that it was as simple as using the children property.

Comment: You're welcome. I was just guessing, and I only needed to check the address of the separators and the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Continued from the comments.*

To access each handle of a `SplitView` separately, you can use its `children` property.
The handles are accessed starting from the second child (`splitView.children[1]`), as the first child is a `QQuickContentItem` containing the *Items* (`splitView.children[0].children`).

*For the following **QML** code:*

```
SplitView {
    id: splitView
    anchors.fill: parent

    handle: Rectangle { implicitWidth: 2; color: 'black' }

    Item { implicitWidth: 50; color: 'green' }
    Item { implicitWidth: 50; color: 'white' }
    Item { implicitWidth: 50; color: 'red' }
}
```

*We can use the **JavaScript** function below:*

```js
function getHandleAt(index: int) {
    return splitView.children[index + 1];
}
```

The handles are accessed starting from the second child, as the first child is the `QQuickContentItem` containing the *Items*.

Answer (score 0):

Because you could never be guaranteed of the order, you cannot say that the `SplitView.handle` will exist before your `SplitView` children. Therefore, the code in `Component.onCompleted` could not be guaranteed to work.

Instead, if you were to bubble up your property, e.g.

```
SplitView {
    id: splitView
    property bool dummy: false
    handle: Rectangle { /* ... */ }
    Rectangle { id: rect1 /* ... */ }
    Rectangle { id: rect2 /* ... */ }
}
```

You can be guaranteed that both SplitView's children and the handle can read/write to it.

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAEJHicrVJNb8IwDL33V1hFQvtS1KKCIBraYReOY0Pj3LWmjZYmVZqC0OC/L6Wlo7TlNJ9iPzu23zNLUqk0LPUyZ8G3xRoueZVCK8kzy3rzI4QfC4x9pJzpT4a7yi+MhRSyc7yO+iKIpcrIhnFOIfUVCl2DqZIpKr2HUOZfHCHMk2RPwSHjOiX2RciRwjsG2hcRx4uO565lTpHRhBIzTcD0moU6puB1ggtkUayv0UByqWi96eLUgKQKswxDGA7BHkxdnE5nNjTqKjscGnWx3KIq65aa8KIhqjt7EIw2XjCxn8Al7n3fR3VaA++jo7BduW/JNTl5rZy4WrtKKl14+BOQnLRo1VXE2Gad5kBHq/2qH7fEUwZzb+nmjp0ubeyB53nNGVYsQdVBCDBhCN/65gBdx2nDKheCiYiCVjl2wJiir/tQKVaKRVEhML2mD+atyPPcnPcMXlrAo4m7YI7//2gd3aK1j9XJ5OLUyqZH6/gLSw8Ijg==)

Comment: The problem with this is that the property is on the splitvew and therefore every item (rectangle) would have its handle affected instead of being independent from each other.